# UIPageViewController *pageViewController = (UIPageViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
UIPageViewController *pageViewController = 
    (UIPageViewController *)self.window.rootViewController
```

After executing this code my `pageviewcontroller` object still contains only nil object. Can anyone help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: You use storyboard for create `pageViewController`?

Comment: What are you trying to do?
the above code makes no sense.

Comment: `self.window` is probably `nil`.  I'm assuming this is in your app delegate.  Have you ever set it?  It doesn't get set by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because either `self.window`or `self.window.rootViewController` is nil. Assuming that this code is in your AppDelegate, make sure that you're assigning the `window` property and it's `rootViewController`.

Comment: The casting won't return null if it's not an instance of `UIPageViewController`.  Casting does no type checking.  Maybe you're thinking of `[NSObject -isKindOfClass:]`?